# make the Exponential interpolation vanish and show it has a unique solution

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

I have several questions concerning different parts of the question:

a) Is it sufficient to show that ${1, e^x,...,e^{nx}}$ are linearly independent over the vector space of differentiable functions on R?

b) For part b, I don't quite understand what it means by "unique solution". Are we supposed to find the unique $a$? If that's the case, any suggestion on how to find it?

c) So I should be looking for something like this: $\mu= e^{-t/n}$? Why is "equally spaced" important in this problem?
Thanks!